# Is there a way to get rid of the rounded corners in Android 12?

Tags: user-interface, android-12

In Android 12, this is the default for widgets, the recents screen and it is hinted in the animations when resuming an activity. Is there a way to remove them and go to the good old squary look?

Comment: Display or icons? What device? Not sure myself, but this info should help in case anyone else knows.

Comment: @l3l-aze In stock Android 12 - regardless of the device (but I have a Redmi Note 9 running crDroid 8.2, in case you're interested) - many elements of the UI present rounded corners. For example: widgets, the long press home menu, the activities in the recents screen, the notification boxes in the notification area, etc. The app icon shape can be configured now as well as in previous versions. However, the rounded corners in the elements I mentioned cannot be removed.